# why receiving link error if not using inline?

Tags: c++

In the following `classA.h`

```
bool IsEqual(const float a, const float b)
{
    return std::fabs(a-b) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
}
```

I receive a **link error**

```
ld: 10 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I add `inline`, everything is fine.

I am wondering why I must add `inline`?

Comment: Because if this header is included in many source files, all of them will have a definition for this function, which is wrong.

Comment: Do you have the linker flag `-all_load`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this function definition is found in multiple translation units (which is usually the case with headers, because you generally include headers in multiple translation units, otherwise what's the point of them?) you get multiple definition errors from the linker.

Only *one* definition per function is allowed.

But marking a function `inline` is a special case that allows you to have this definition in multiple translation units, as long as the definitions are identical. The language *had* to provide this, because inlining functions is most effective when the definitions are immediately available (i.e. in the same translation unit, i.e. probably in a header); that `inline` doesn't really inherently cause actual inlining in this modern age of super-intelligent optimisers doesn't change that fact of the language.

Comment: Strictly speaking, if c++ choose to ignore the `inline` directive, linkage errors can still occur, which wouldn't occur if the function is truly inlined in the traditional sense. See e.g. what happens to inlined functions in header-only libraries like Eigen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997846

Comment: @TingL: That's a completely different issue. _This_ question is about the relaxing of the one-definition rule, which is mandated by C++ (read 3.2/3 and 3.2/5).

Answer (score 3):

The same function symbol `IsEqual` will be defined multiple times, if you include the header file in multiple source files.

Traditionally and in your particular case, it is OK when you make the function `inline` because the function is not actually defined, and the function body is substituted on each call site.

Alternatively, you can define the function body in a classA.cpp, and declare the `classA.h`

```
#ifndef __CLASS_HEADER_
#define __CLASS_HEADER_
bool IsEqual(const float a, const float b);
#endif
```

Still another possibility is to declare `IsEqual` as a static member of some class in `classA.h`.

Comment: `It is OK when you make the function inline because the function is not actually defined, and the function body is substituted on each call site.` The inline keyword guarantees no such thing and, in fact, in modern times the compiler will ignore the keyword (for everything other than this linkage rule) and decide for itself what's best.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indeed, there is no guarantee that `inline` is truly inlined in current C++. This is most disturbing for header-only c++ libraries as compiler choose to ignore `inline` and cause multiple-link errors.

Answer (score 2):

Because otherwise `IsEqual` has multiple definitions, one for each time you include it.